In what order does git-am apply patches and is there a way to influence it
I saved the patch-emails from a mailing list to a maildir at /tmp/mypatches. Now it seems that git-am will just take the patches in the lexicological order of the filenames in the maildir and apply them in that order. Because if I manually rename the files into the correct order, the patches apply fine. Is there any way to get git-am to order them differently, maybe in the order of the Subject line?
